# Excel: Getting sum total based on date input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Thanks for the previous help, now I have another issue that I cant figure out.

If you look at the image, I have the data spread out in groups.
I tried "+" and "&" to add additional line to include the rows 5 and 9 but that didnt work but that didnt sum up when setting the date to use.

=SUM(INDEX(Data!$A:$Z, MATCH($C5, Data!$B:$B, 0), MATCH($D$3, Data!$1:$1, 0)):
     INDEX(Data!$A:$Z, IFERROR(MATCH($C6, Data!$B:$B, 0)-1, MATCH(1E+99, Data!D:D)), MATCH($D$3, Data!$1:$1, 0)))

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the start and stop cells of the SUM range. This can be done with INDEX and a couple of MATCH's.

In Dashboard!D5 use this formula and fill down.

```
=SUM(INDEX(Data!$A:$Z, MATCH($C5, Data!$B:$B, 0), MATCH($D$3, Data!$1:$1, 0)):
     INDEX(Data!$A:$Z, IFERROR(MATCH($C6, Data!$B:$B, 0)-1, MATCH(1E+99, Data!D:D)), MATCH($D$3, Data!$1:$1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, that worked well but now I ran into another issue.

Answer (score 1):

*This tricky method solves the issue:*

[image]

***K***ey Feature is, **H**elper Value.

**How it works:**

- Insert `=A16` in Cell `G16`.
- Formula in Cell `G17` & fill down:

  `=IF(A17="",G16,A17)`
- Formula in Cell `J16`, in `Dashboard Tab`:

  `=IF(SUMIFS(Data!C$16:C$24,Data!$G$16:$G$24,$I16)=0,"",SUMIFS(Data!C$16:C$24,Data!$G$16:$G$24,$I16))`

**N.B.**

- *Fill the formula across.*
- *For neatness, later on you may hide the **H**elper Column then your sheet will look like this.*

[image]

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*